# Semaphores Mutex Locks preventing Deadlocks - C Program

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I have a multithreaded application in C - there are 3 threads and to prevent synchronisation issues/deadlocks I am using Semaphores and mutex locks. 1 thread is consumer, 1 thread a producer and 1 thread is a monitor that outputs the values updated by consumer/producer thread. Initialised semaphores

```
sem_init(&empty, 0, 10);
sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
```

The data is synchronised in producer by

```
//decide to go into critical section
sem_wait(&empty);
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
Attempt_Park();
/* release locks */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
/* signal full */
sem_post(&full);
```

And similar for consumer. However I do not know how to use the semaphore with the monitor thread that outputs the current data (of a linked list) - currently I am only using a mutex lock but I know that eventually that it is going to be a problem

```
//user presses enter
/* Acquire lock */
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
//output data to screen
```

As this thread is not involved in changing the data I cannot use the semaphore to get the thread to wait but the producer or consumer could change the data when monitor thread is writing to the screen. Should have I used a binary semaphore? If so I cannot work out how to apply it.

Comment: For your monitor, use a condition variable and have the producer/consumer signal a predicate change when the state changes.

Comment: Am I correct in my assumption that this implementation places the thread into the waiting state when thread calls wait() on a semaphore with a value of zero hence no cpu cycling?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the monitor thread to run only when producer or consumer thread modifies the data. No need to bother about locking mechanism for the monitor thread. use signaling mechanism to wake the thread in order to output your data

Answer (score 0):

Dont have too many locking it would degrade your performance. Think for your requirement one mutex should suffice as only producer and consume threads would be entering critical section.

Comment: My point is though that monitor thread needs to prevent the consumer or produced from changing the data while writing output to the screen so the monitor thread requires that there is data synchronisation